# Add the little button to the right side of a cell indicating number of rows in drop down list

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, drop-down-menu

[image: list displays menu after clicking drop down][image: sample image displaying number of items of drop down list in a cell]
friends
I have an iphone app with tableview drop down list using objective C.How do i add a small button at side of cell displaying number of items in drop down list

Comment: As you have created a custom cell, similarly place a button beside the item count

Comment: i cant get you please give clear idea. I have used placed button in customized cell and how to display the number of items in that button!! what is the logic should i use to get those number of items in that button

Comment: Definitely you would have array of dropdown items, so just count array items and display in related cell and If you are using image to show numbers then basis on condition show related image

Comment: thats i am asking how can i do it programmatically count number of array items instead of adding manually in the button.

Comment: Share your array or dictionary code for table items and dropdown items that you are displaying in table

Comment: demoData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // We'll give five values, from one to five.
    [demoData addObject:@"One"];
    [demoData addObject:@"Two"];
    [demoData addObject:@"Three"];
    [demoData addObject:@"Four"];
    [demoData addObject:@"Five"];
   // Initially, the isShowingList value will be set to NO.
    // We don't want the list to be dislplayed when the view loads.
    isshowingList = NO;
 if (!isshowingList)
        {
           
  [[cell textLabel] setText:[demoData objectAtIndex:selectedValueIndex]];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
  }

Comment: in the above in the place of disclosure indicator i wanna display number of items displays below drop down in list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79516/discussion-between-sujay-and-gopinath).

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified if it's for Objective-C or Swift, I can't really give you any specific code.

General premise is to customize the table view cells. 
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

There's a great tutorial there on the concept, in Objective-C code, for how to do it. But if you don't post any code that you've tried or the code you have currently, not much else I can do.

You're going to have to add a button, and the button title needs to be the number of rows in the list.

Comment: i am asking about logic how to get those number of items that displays in drop down list in that button

Comment: i can do customizing table view cell but how can i display how many  amount of items displayed in dropdown list in the cell at corner. we will use accessory disclosure indicator to display arrow at the cell while clicking that drop down menu appears. How to replace that with number of items displays in list